# How can I call a js script that is inside a php echo

Tags: javascript, php, function

My whole website pretty much uses php, even for html.

I'm trying to call a function on a onchange event for my input:

I've tried and tried and can't get it to work. I even tried just plain js functions but nothing.

It just won't call the function unless it's in plain html.

```
$data.=  '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="" onchange="<script type=\'text/javascript\'>alert(\'ehh\')></script>"</td>';
```

Also tried:

```
$data.=  '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="" onchange="<script type=\'text/javascript\'>test();></script>"</td>';
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Others have already told you how to fix this so it works, but what you are doing is so so wrong in other ways. Inline event handlers are bad anyway, you should attach them with javascript (look up `addEventListener`). Even more important... (see next comment)

Comment: ...don't try to output large amounts of HTML, including `<script>` tags, as PHP string literals. This is guaranteed to be unreadable and make you make errors with quotes all over the place. (It will also break any syntax highlighting that your editor would do for HTML and JS.) A `.php` file will output, unchanged, anything outside `<?php ?>` tags - so write most of your file like that and only use PHP where you need to for dynamically-generated content.

Comment: I don't really like having php and html tags in the same file makes it a bit messy and ugly imo

Comment: @BrandonGx97: Keep in mind that your preferred approach is *mixing three different languages on one line of code*.  That’s just begging for syntax errors.  In this question alone, on just this one line, you’ve already encountered two such errors.  You should expect to encounter many more with this approach.

Comment: "I don't really like having php and html tags in the same file "...well you've already got that now, they're just inside echo statements that's all. It's much easier to read them when they aren't, and as others have said it's also less likely that you'll make mistakes when you're writing them. IMO all those extra escaped quote marks are the ugly thing, not the switching between PHP and HTML :-).

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't PHP, it's that this is entirely malformed HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" value="" onchange="<script type=\'text/javascript\'>test();></script>"
```

You don't need a `<script>` element *inside the `onchange` attribute*.  Assuming you've defined your `test` function somewhere on the page, you can just call it in the `onchange` attribute:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" value="" onchange="test()">
```

Comment: how can I call a function with a php variable?
$data.=  '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="" onchange="test(this, '.$var.')"</td>';

Comment: @BrandonGx97: You can output your PHP values to the page exactly like you would anywhere else in the page.  What have you tried and what didn't work?  As a tip, when you make your attempt if it doesn't work as expected then your first step should be to examine the resulting HTML page source and see if it's what you expect, and check the browser's JavaScript console for errors.  Once you have an attempt and a specific problem, that sounds like a good start for another Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I tried what I Just posted and that's how I add php inside a echo of html
this is in the error:
https://i.imgur.com/R1BlKvE.png

Comment: @BrandonGx97: And how did it fail?  I don't know what's in `$var` or what the intended result is.  But in general concatenating string literals and variables works for outputting PHP values.  **Edit:** That looks like a JavaScript error.  So what was the output in the page source?  For example, if `$var` is a string then you're missing the quotes in your JavaScript.

Comment: yes, It's a string.

Comment: you're right, I got it. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't put `<script>` tags inside `onXXX` attributes. Just put the JavaScript statements.

```
$data.=  '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="" onchange="alert(\'ehh\')"</td>';
```